# Why FF is preferred browser to set proxy ?

Tags: security, browser, proxy, burp

What is the actual reason to choose Firefox to configure along with Proxy tools like Burp Suite or ZAP ? i.e. Is FF is providing something more than other browser's when it comes to proxy setting ?

Comment: Burp works with most browsers. Firefox used to be popular with pen testers because of the add-ons available, but these days most use Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox has its own proxy settings, independent of the system proxy. Other browsers (IE, Chrome) use the system proxy, which may require more privileges to set and setting the system proxy affects more things outside the browser.